# How to sum previous and next row values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

After trying several hours i am still not able to perform the following task.
I would like to sum to my center points the previous and next row value as shown in the image below

[image: sum previous and next value to middle points]

Can you please provide me with an example how that can be done?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [`DF.rolling.sum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) by providing `center=True` (*Since by default the labels are set to the right edge of the window*)  and then take every third slice from it. Additionally, you can set the minimum number of observations, `min_periods` to be equal to 1 which basically says no output values will be set until at least `min_periods` non-null values are encountered.

```
df.A.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1, center=True).sum().iloc[::3].astype(int)

1      30
4     120
7     210
10    190
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 3):

This will get it done

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.arange(10, 101, 10)), np.arange(1, 11))

pd.Series(np.convolve(df.A.values, [1, 1, 1])[1::3], df.index[0::3])

1      30
4     120
7     210
10    190
dtype: int64

​
```